# How can I graph the bouncing of a ball

Tags: graphing-functions, education, mathematical-modeling

If a ball is dropped vertically from a height of $h_1$, after it bounces, it will reach a height that is less than $h_1$, depending on the coefficient of restitution, $e$, $(0<e<1)$. This bounce can be plotted on a graph with time as the x axis.

$y(t)= h+v_yt-4.9t^2$

The equation above is a parabola that represents the motion of the object under constant acceleration.

Assuming that the ball starts from a specific height with $e=0.85$, how can I approach creating the next parabola that can model the bounce of the ball?

I have tried Googling this issue, but it mostly results in game design/coding which is hard to understand.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution    (There are also the formulas for the velocities in this article)